# echo not showing up on my php page?

Tags: php

Here is my code for my home page. I am trying to test php is working with 'echo' but the echo text doesn't show up on the homepage. I have saved the file as php but the echo "recent posts 1" does not show up on the page

```
<head>
<title>1WD HTML5 theme</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```
<header class="mainHeader">
    <img src="img/logo.png">
    <nav><ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
</header>

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">   
            <article class="topcontent">    
                <header>
                    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
                </header>


                <content>
                        <?php
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                echo "recent post 1";
                ?>

                </content>

            </article>


    </div>

            <aside class="top-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2>Top Sidebar</h2>
                <p>test</p>
                </article>
            </aside>

            <aside class="middle-sidebar">
                <article>
                <h2>Middle Sidebar</h2>
                <p>test</p>
                </article>
            </aside>                


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the real question is: how are you trying to access this and where?

Comment: tell page name with extension. like abc.php or abc.html

Comment: I've 2 educated guesses for this.

Comment: yoohoo?!? comments/answers given here, where are you Mr./Miss OP? dinner?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't comment.

But if you don't have a server support PHP you can't run the file.

I mean you can't run the file in your "PC" you need upload the file to web hosting or set up your computer as server. (You can install WampServer, XAMPP etc..)

Comment: *"Well, I can't comment."* - 2 more rep points and you will ;-) Edit: there you go. Welcome to "commenting"

Comment: So have some on me! Now you can comment in comments

Comment: I was glad to help you @ziggy (:
Fred-ii- RiggsFolly Thanks ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Edit: Oh.. comment disappeared. Re-edit: ah, there it is.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears correct in format, but you cannot just display PHP code without a server. If you are testing this by opening the file in your browser, it will not work. You need to either look into XAMPP a useful cross platform server solution for free or if you have a hosting provider for a website, testing your code on that server. Hope that helps.

Here is some information on [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Comment: This is just an educated guess that you are attempting to open PHP pages without going through a server of some sort. If you are, this answer is irrelevant. :)

Comment: ...which was "one" of my "educated" guesses Chris ;-) The other... well, it's the "how" they're trying to access their file. Your answer is relevant.

Comment: HAHAHA! Thanks, Fred. I could have saved time if I could comment too, but I see you were already heading that way!

Comment: You're welcome Chris. Yeah, their "way" is unknownst to us, and I/we see this quite often. `http://localhost/file.php` and `file:///file.php` are two different animals altogether. One of which will fail and shouldn't be the former. ;-)